# Can't escape a while loop, Python 2.7

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

For some reason i can't escape  while loop , i tried debugging it, and looks like for loop is untouched and i don't understand why.
(it's fraction of mine tictactoe game code)

```
users_main = []
computers_main = []
while True:
    computers_storage = []
    users_storage = []
    if 0==0:
        condition = True
        while condition:
            guess_y = int(raw_input('Enter coordinate y:')) -1
            guess_x = int(raw_input('Enter coordinate x:')) -1
            users_storage.append(guess_y)
            users_storage.append(guess_x)
            users_main.append(users_storage)
            for a in computers_main:
                if a == users_storage:
                    del users_storage[-2]
                    del users_main[-1]
                    condition = True
                    break
                else:
                    condition = False
                    break
break
```

Comment: remove if 0 == 0:, move condition = True to the top of the script.  See if that helps.

Comment: You never add anything to `computers_main`. You're asking Python to do something "For every element in an empty list", which is basically saying "Do something 0 times." That's why your for list is never run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only *break* when *computers_main* has values in it, since you are not storing any values, the line:

```
for a in computers_main:
```

does not iterate anything because the list is empty.  Therefore the break within this  *for loop* is never reached.

Answer (score 1):

```
if 0 == 0
```

is never going to be untrue

```
while True:
```

While *what* is true?

Answer (score 1):

```
users_main = []
computers_main = []
while True:
    computers_storage = []
    users_storage = []
    if 0==0:
        condition = True
        while condition:
            guess_y = int(raw_input('Enter coordinate y:')) -1
            guess_x = int(raw_input('Enter coordinate x:')) -1
            users_storage.append(guess_y)
            users_storage.append(guess_x)
            users_main.append(users_storage)
            for a in computers_main:
                if a == users_storage:
                    del users_storage[-2]
                    del users_main[-1]
                    condition = True
                    break  # RIGHT HERE
                else:
                    condition = False
                    break  # AND HERE
```

The places where I marked "right here" and "and here", you are only escaping the inner loop, and not escaping the `while True` loop or the `while condition` loop.
Also, I've noticed several weird things in your code that might have been not intended:

```
if 0==0:
    condition = True
    while condition:
```

That code is equivalent to just using `while True:`.

Also, `int(raw_input())` can be replaced with `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your **condition** for the **while (condition)** loop stays **True**.

The **computers_main** list stays empty, thus the code in the

> for a in computers_main:

loop is never entered, and thus **condition** is never changed (stays **True**).

Answer (score 0):

The 'break' statement on the 19th or 21st line of your code only terminates the nested while-loop, leaving the outer loop as it is. So the outer loop, which is a infinite loop

```
while True:
```

continues to run even if the nested loop gets terminated in each iteration. So another condition is to be added to terminate the outer while loop. You can use another break statement:

```
while True:
    computers_storage = []
    ...
    if 0==0:
        while condition:
                ...
                ...
                condition = True
                break 
            else:
                condition = False
                break  
         break
```